# How can I make a shortcut to a module that runs unittest.main() and then allows the Python interpreter to remain open?

Tags: python, unit-testing, command-line-arguments, python-unittest

I am developing a package that uses unittest for its tests. The tests are all in a submodule called tests. At the bottom of the submodule is this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But if you run the module, Windows closes the command window before one can read the output. OK, this is not a new problem. There are ways around this, for example making a shortcut that looks something like:

```
cmd /k "python -m mypackage.tests"
```

This works, now you get to see the output. But then you are dumped back at the `C:\Windows\System32` command prompt. It would be nicer to be able to still be in the Python interpreter, so that I can play around in Python if something occurs to me to check after I saw the tests. So you try something like this:

```
cmd /k "python -i -m mypackage.tests"
```

But, whoa, what's this? after the test output, you see

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Docs\programs\python\mypackage\tests.py", line 274, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\unittest\main.py", line 125, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\unittest\main.py", line 267, in runTests
    sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
SystemExit: True
>>>
```

You are still in the Python interpreter, but now for some reason there are several lines of dumb noise in between the test results and the new prompt. No-one wants to see that. It is presumably because `unittest.main()` tries to exit the interpreter but the interpreter doesn't let it happen because you used the `-i` option. Which is good in a way, but the traceback isn't wanted.

You look at [the documentation for unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) to see if there is a way to make Python stick around after running the tests. There are no command line switches for unittest that have this effect, but there is a keyword argument `exit` that could be used to prevent unittest from trying to close Python. So we could change the end of tests.py to this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(exit = False)
```

The problem with this is that sometimes you might want the default behaviour of closing the interpreter, like say if you had your version control software run the tests module automatically. So it would be best to have some way of conditionally disabling the exit. Well, it seems like by implementing a rudimentary check for command line options this could be done. So we try changing it to

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    unittest.main(exit = 'noexit' not in ''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

and the shortcut to

```
cmd /k "python -i -m mypackage.tests --noexit"
```

But now when you run it the tests don't even run, instead you see a big wall of complaints about how there's no option called "noexit":

```
Usage: tests.py [options]

tests.py: error: no such option: --noexit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\optparse.py", line 1391, in parse_args
    stop = self._process_args(largs, rargs, values)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\optparse.py", line 1431, in _process_args
    self._process_long_opt(rargs, values)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\optparse.py", line 1484, in _process_long_opt
    opt = self._match_long_opt(opt)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\optparse.py", line 1469, in _match_long_opt
    return _match_abbrev(opt, self._long_opt)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\optparse.py", line 1674, in _match_abbrev
    raise BadOptionError(s)
optparse.BadOptionError: no such option: --noexit

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Docs\programs\python\mypackage\tests.py", line 275, in <module>
    unittest.main(exit = 'noexit' not in ''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\unittest\main.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\unittest\main.py", line 148, in parseArgs
    options, args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
  File "C:\Python33\lib\optparse.py", line 1393, in parse_args
    self.error(str(err))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\optparse.py", line 1573, in error
    self.exit(2, "%s: error: %s\n" % (self.get_prog_name(), msg))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\optparse.py", line 1563, in exit
    sys.exit(status)
SystemExit: 2
```

Well I think I should be the one who decides what command line options there are, but maybe I haven't gone through the correct formalities to declare what command line options I'll accept. But actually, no, that isn't the case, because if I comment out the line that calls unittest.main():

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    #unittest.main(exit = 'noexit' not in ''.join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

then there is no complaining at all, just a `>>>` prompt! From which I can only deduce that `unittest.main()` is for some reason inspecting the command line arguments to my script, and throwing a hissy fit when they don't meet its standards - this despite the fact that they aren't directed at it in the first place. This wouldn't be so much of a problem if there were a command line switch that made it hang around instead of exiting (like the `exit` keyword argument does), but there isn't.

What's the answer? Every option seems unsatisfactory in one way or another.

Comment: What happens if you just do `python /path/to/test.py --noexit` (no `-m`) with your `unittest.main(exit = 'noexit' not in ''.join(sys.argv[1:])` hack?

Comment: By the way, what version of python are you using?  I'm surprised to see an exception from `optparse` in there -- `unittest` seems to use `argparse` in python2.7....

Comment: @mgilson, a package-relative import at the start of the submodule provokes this: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`. Python v3.3